# How to get JSON data with two arrays in android

Tags: android, json

I want to get one array from PHP that one of the fileds is an array.
How can get basket's data with jsonArray and jsonObject ?
(In the code below, the basket is an array that contains 5 parameters).

It's my array:

```
 [{"orderCode":11514,"orderDate":"2017/05/21","orderPrice":"1‌​9200","fullName":"Ja‌​ck","address":"addr 1","cellphone":"09151515730","basket":[{"b_qty":"4","pid":"8‌​","b_price":"9500","‌​b_discount":"10","ti‌​tle":"obj1"}]
```

**Edit**

```
  String b_price ="";
    String b_discount="";
    String b_qty ="";
    String ti‌​tle= "";
    String pid="";

    try 
      {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(data);

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String orderCode = object.getString("orderCode");
            String orderDate = object.getString("orderDate");
            String orderPrice = object.getString("orderPrice");
            String fullName = object.getString("fullName");
            String address = object.getString("address");
            String cellphone = object.getString("cellphone");
           
            JSONArray orderBasket = object.getJSONArray("basket");

            for (int j = 0; j < orderBasket.length(); j++){
                JSONObject object1 = orderBasket.getJSONObject(j);

                b_qty = object1.getString("b_qty");
                pid = object1.getString("pid");
                b_price = object1.getString("b_price");
                b_discount = object1.getString("b_discount");
                ti‌​tle = object1.getString("ti‌​tle");

            }

            CustomOrderList customOrderList = new CustomOrderList(getApplicationContext());
            customOrderList.orderCode.setText(orderCode);
            customOrderList.orderDate.setText(orderDate);
            customOrderList.orderTotalPrice.setText(orderPrice);
            customOrderList.orderFullName.setText(fullName);
            customOrderList.orderAddress.setText(address);
            customOrderList.orderCellphone.setText(cellphone);
           
            customOrderList.basketPrice.setText(b_price);
            customOrderList.basketDiscount.setText(b_discount);
            customOrderList.basketTitle.setText(ti‌​tle);

            layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            linearOrders.addView(customOrderList);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
```

}

Comment: Add a your json from and explain more what you want to do

Comment: I see you treat "basket" as string here. I don't fully understand what you want to achieve, the code here is not quite relevant, post the JSON structure you are dealing with ! and then tell us what you want to extract

Comment: I want to show basket's data under other details in my app.] I get other data with this code correctly but I can't get basket's data with this code.

Comment: @Saeidhp If basket is an array then use this JSONArray orderBasket = object.getJSONArray("basket"); to retrieve

Comment: It means I should use for loop in main for ? May you explain your code ?

Comment: It's my array: [{"orderCode":11514,"orderDate":"1396/05/21","orderPrice":"19200","fullName":"Jack","address":"addr 1","cellphone":"09151515730","basket":[{"b_qty":"4","pid":"8","b_price":"9500","b_discount":"10","title":"obj1"}]

Comment: @Saeidhp See basket here represents jsonarray. So to fetch jsonarray write the above code . Now in that area you have single json object. So you can get that json by orderbasket.getJsonObject(0). So you got your json of basket now. Parse it's keys now and use it

Comment: it's not worked or I don't understand.
may you write sample code for this issue?

Comment: Sure wait a min

Comment: @Saeidhp See my answer. Code accordingly i have explained you the concept.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

        String orderCode = object.getString("orderCode");
        String orderDate = object.getString("orderDate");
        String orderPrice = object.getString("orderPrice");
        String fullName = object.getString("fullName");
        String address = object.getString("address");
        String cellphone = object.getString("cellphone");

//Now orderBasket is jsonArray
        JSONArray orderBasket = object.getJSONArray("basket");

 // So fetch all objects from orderBasket array
      for (int j = 0; j < orderBasket.length(); j++){
       JSONObject objectbsk = orderBasket.getJSONObject(j);

        String b_qty = objectbsk.getString("b_qty");
        String pid = objectbsk.getString("pid");
        String b_price = objectbsk.getString("b_price");
        String b_discount = objectbsk.getString("b_discount");
        String ti‌​tle = objectbsk.getString("ti‌​tle");
// Create a orderBasket list for Basket with these keys also as you have created for CustomOrderList and use it
}

        CustomOrderList customOrderList = new CustomOrderList(getApplicationContext());
        customOrderList.orderCode.setText(orderCode);
        customOrderList.orderDate.setText(orderDate);
        customOrderList.orderTotalPrice.setText(orderPrice);
        customOrderList.orderFullName.setText(fullName);
        customOrderList.orderAddress.setText(address);
        customOrderList.orderCellphone.setText(cellphone);
    customOrderList.orderBasket.setText(orderBasket);

// here you can't do set text since it's jsonarray. So use basketlist to show the data`

 layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            linearOrders.addView(customOrderList);
        }
```

Comment: May you check your code ? this code has error customOrderList.orderBasket.setText(orderBasket); and I changed i to j in this part  for (int j = 0; i < orderBasket.length(); j++){
       JSONObject object = orderBasket.getJSONObject(i); but not worked

Comment: Yaah I have edited that i to j . And the first line which you were telling is I have written in my answer that you cannot settext a jsonarray(orderbasket). So create a listoforderbasket...Please read my edited answer .Hope it helps

Comment: Sorry for repeating the question. I had to edited my question like your code but it's not working too.Please read my edited question.

Comment: The output is null.

Comment: @Saeidhp Please check whether response is coming from the api or not.

Comment: Yes, I get response in log like above array.

Comment: @Saeidhp. So what is null exactly. Please debug it properly

Comment: I debug it.the problem related title but I don't khnow why ?!  I comment ti‌​tle = object1.getString("ti‌​tle"); and output show. I should check more.I'll tell you when the code is answered.

Comment: @Saeidhp Yaah sure.

Comment: Hi  Aditya Srivastava, unfortunately I can't get complete output. I just can show first row of basket.

Comment: Yes because you have taken the string and string can store only single value at a time. You have to use arraylist for that.

Comment: I changed the string to array string but just one row (last row) shown.Could you help me with sample code ?